# Using Dotfuscator for 32 bit and 64 bit setup

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, debugging, dotfuscator

I am working on a aplication in  vs08 for both the x86 and x64 platform I have created two configrations x86 and x64 for both the platforms but when I add Dotfuscator project in the solution of the project and then I am unable to prepare two above configration for dotfuscator project to encript the .exes of both the platform.I want to do so because both the .exes are required to create on the different locations after building the project. Can anyone help me to do so.

Comment: From where are you executing it? Post-build? How are you referencing the path?

Comment: Actually,I have add the dotfuscator project form the project property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The x64 platform is not relevant for a managed program.  Only for unmanaged ones.  The jitter can generate 32-bit or 64-bit machine code from the same assembly.  Directed by the operating system type and the Platform target setting in Project + Properties, Build tab.

Answer (score 0):

The visual studio integration of Dotfuscator is not currently able to differentiate between x86 and x64 builds of the same project. This is a known bug which we are working to fix. In the mean time, you can set up config files through the standalone UI and then run the obfuscation as a post-build step if you need to automatically obfuscate both the x86 and x64 binaries.